# Vuetify - How to access element in v-data-table at current cursor position

Tags: vuetify.js, v-data-table

I'm using v-data-table to list locations that are also shown on a map.
It would be nice to synchronize the highlighting so that if the cursor hovers over a
location in the table, the same location would be highlighted on the map.

Is there a way to access the element in v-data-table where the cursor is currently hovering over?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As one of the possible solutions you can override `#items` slot and include native `mouseover` event into `<tr>` tag:

```js
<span class="text-h6">{{ `Last hovered location: ${hoveredLocation}` }}</span>
<v-data-table
  :headers="headers"
  :items="locations"
  :items-per-page="5"
>
  <template #item="{ item }">
    <tr @mouseover="onMouseOver(item)">
      <td>{{ item.city }}</td>
      <td>{{ item.country }}</td>
    </tr>
  </template>
</v-data-table>
...
data () {
  return {
    hoveredLocation: null,
    headers: [
      { text: 'City', value: 'city' },
      { text: 'Country', value: 'country' },
    ],
    locations: [
      { id: 3, city: 'Paris', country: 'France'},
      ...
    ],
  }
},
methods: {
  onMouseOver(item) {
    this.hoveredLocation = `${item.city} (${item.country})`;
  }
}
```

Possibly you need to combine several events like `mouseover/out`, `mouseenter/leave`, etc.

Test this [at CodePen](https://codepen.io/betanet/pen/XWzvEEd).